# Proper way to rethrow an exception

Tags: c#, exception

I have the following methods in c#:

```
void Method1()
{
    try
    {
        Method2();
    }
    catch(Method2Exception ex)
    {
        //Log error
    }
}

void Method2()
{
    if(error)
    {
        throw(new Method2Exception("error"));
    }

    //Do something and call method3
    try
    {
        Method3();
    }
    catch(Method3Exception)
    {
        //??
    }
}

void Method3()
{
    //Do something
    if(error)
    {
        throw(new Method3Exception("error"));
    }
}
```

Method3 its gonna be call by different methods and it returns Method3Exception and I need rethrow the exception from Method2 to Method1 but I don't want catch Method3Exception on Method1. what's the best way to do that?

Any suggestions

Comment: Do you *really* need to catch exceptions in `Method2`? It looks like `catch` overusing.

Comment: My project is a layer architecture, Method1 is my presentation layer, Method2 is my bussiness layer and Method3 is an alternative Method of bussiness layer and y catch and log errors in presentation layer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative way to re-throwing the exception (using `throw;` as described in other answers) is to wrap the exception in inner exception. As described in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173163.aspx#Anchor_1), all custom exceptions should have at least four constructors, and one of them is

```
public InvalidDepartmentException(string message, System.Exception inner) : base(message, inner) { }
```

So if all your custom exceptions are like this, you could wrap the exception from `Method3` as inner exception:

```
void Method2()
{
    if(error)
    {
        throw(new Method2Exception("error"));
    }

    //Do something and call method3
    try
    {
        Method3();
    }
    catch(Method3Exception exc)
    {
        throw new Method2Exception("error", exc); // exc is passed as inner exception
    }
}
```

Then if you want to inspect the inner exception in `Method1`, you can use property `InnerException`:

```
void Method1()
{
    try
    {
        Method2();
    }
    catch(Method2Exception ex)
    {
        if(ex.InnerException != null)
        {
            var message = ex.InnerException.Message;
            // Do what you need with the message
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The term (re)throw usally refer to throwing the exception back to the caller preserving the stack trace (which contains where the exception exactly occurred). This can be done using `throw;` without specifying the exception operand contrary to `throw ex`:

```
try
{
    Method3();
}
catch(Method3Exception)
{
    throw;
}
```

**However**, if you're just going to add a throw **with nothing before it** in that method. It is useless, just remove the try..catch and the exception is going to propagate to the caller which is the default behavior.

[Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ah5wsex.aspx):

> A throw statement can be used in a catch block to re-throw the
>   exception that the catch block caught. In this case, the throw
>   statement does not take an exception operand.

Comment: You're right, but I need catch Method2Exception or Method3Exception in the same catch on Method1

Answer (score 0):

In `Method2`, you can throw a new `Method2Exception` with the existing `Method3Exception` as its `InnerException`:

```
try
{
    Method3();
}
catch(Method3Exception method3Exception)
{
    throw new Method2Exception("Message", method3Exception);
}
```

Then you can catch the `Method2Exception` above:

```
try
{
    Method2();
}
catch(Method2Exception ex)
{
    //Log error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions are bubbles up by default. For example,

```
void FirstMethod()
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 10;
    int c = b / a;
}

void SecondMethod()
{
    FirstMethod();
}

void ThirdMethod()
{
    SecondMethod();
}

void FourthMethod()
{
    try
    {
        ThirdMethod();
    }
    catch (DivideByZeroException ex)
    {
        // Handle error
    } 
}
```

The exception will occur in *FirstMethod* and it will go upwards and will be cought at *ForurthMethod*. If you want to *log* the exception at *ThirdMethod* for example, but still want your exception to be handled at *FourthMethod* then you have to options:

### First option:

```
void ThirdMethod()
{
    try
    {
        SecondMethod();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Log the error
        throw; // Throw exception without affecting StackTrace
    }   
}
```

### Second option:

After C# 6.0 you can do this with ease by using exception filters. Create a logger method which returns *false*.

```
bool Log(Exception ex)
{
    // Log the error
    return false;
}
```

Add *exception filter* in third method:

```
void ThirdMethod()
{
    try
    {
        SecondMethod();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) when(Log(ex))
    {
        // Debugger won't reach here
    }   
}
```